# create mysql query to get total sale amount based on items price change

Tags: mysql, join

I want to create a mysql query to get total sale amount based on its source but price may be change 
i.e. either price increase or price decrease.

My database tables are:

```
items(itemId,itemSize,itemColor,.......)
prices(priceId,presentPriceBoolean,priceDate,itemPrice,items_itemId)
shipments(shipmentId,shipmentPairs,shipmentDate,items_itemId,sources_sourceId)
sales(saleId,sellByCashier,saleDate)
soldItems(soldItemId,soldItemType,quantitySold,discount,items_itemId,sales_saleId)
sources(sourceId,sourceName,......)
```

For example:

view: shipment of items

```
itemId  shipmentDate    shipmentQuantity    Price   Source
     1  12/01/2015                     5     1500   Bata
     1  16/01/2015                    10     1700   Bata
```

view: Sale of items

```
itemId  saleQuantity    Discount    SaleDate    Source
     1             2           0    12/01/2015  Bata
     1             1         100    13/01/2015  Bata
     1             2         200    18/01/2015  Bata
```

The above information shows that 5 pairs of item shipment occured at price 1500 on 12/01/2015(shipmentDate) and first 2 pairs are sold on 12/01/2015(saleDate) and then 1 pair is sold on 13/01/2015(saleDate).
Later on, 10 pairs of item shipment occured again at price 1700 on 16/01/2015(shipmentDate) and 2 pairs are sold on 18/01/2015(saleDate).

Query should calculate the sale amount based on the price which is active during a period i.e. price which is active from one shipmentDate to next shipmentDate.

Final result would be like that as can be seen from the above two views:

```
SUM(price * saleQuantity - discount)

(1500 * 2 - 0) + (1500 * 1 - 100) + (1700 * 2 - 200) = 7600
```

Final Result:

```
sourceName  saleAmount
Bata        7600
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: i figured out what i was looking for. Thanks for your consideration. :)

Comment: In that case, can you either submit the answer below or remove this question? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Strawberry, ya sure. I figured out it by adding a foreign key in the individual sale items table which helped me to know that whether a price increase or decrease, I am able to record its price which was first a nightmare. Cheers. Thanks. ;)